# Difference between execution policies and when to use them

Tags: c++, c++17

I noticed that a majority (if not all) functions in `<algorithm>` are getting one or more extra overloads. All of these extra overloads add a specific new parameter, for example, `std::for_each` goes from:

```
template< class InputIt, class UnaryFunction >
UnaryFunction for_each( InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryFunction f );
```

to:

```
template< class ExecutionPolicy, class InputIt, class UnaryFunction2 >
void for_each( ExecutionPolicy&& policy, InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryFunction2 f );
```

What effect does this extra `ExecutionPolicy` have on these functions?

What are the differences between:

- `std::execution::seq`
- `std::execution::par`
- `std::execution::par_unseq`

And when to use one or the other?

Comment: Also http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t has the description of each

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall How did I miss that.. It doesn't seem to give good code examples though. I guess that'll just come in time.

Comment: @Gill Bates - Though, using ::par doesn't make life much easier: "When using parallel execution policy, it is the programmer's responsility to avoid deadlocks"

Comment: A typo: for the signature with execution policy argument, we should use ForwardIt instead of InputIt. (Cf. [Anthony Williams’ book](https://www.manning.com/books/c-plus-plus-concurrency-in-action-second-edition) page 332-333 or cppref).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`seq` means "execute sequentially" and is the exact same thing as the version without an execution policy.

`par` means "execute in parallel", which permits the implementation to execute on multiple threads in parallel. You are responsible for making sure that no data races happen within `f`.

`par_unseq` means that in addition to being allowed to execute in multiple threads, the implementation is also allowed to interleave individual loop iterations within a single thread, i.e. load multiple elements and execute `f` on all of them only afterwards. This is required to permit a vectorized implementation.

Comment: In a Cppcon16 talk was mentioned, that the `seq` policy behaves as `par`, but kind of only in the calling thread, to make debugging easier and that it is not the same as the algorithm without an execution policy. I try to find the reference.

Comment: @Serthy I believe you might be thinking of Bryce Lelbach’s Boostcon 2016 talk about the language and library changes in C++17. Both the video (YouTube) and a PDF (Github) of the presentation slides (sans explanation about seq for debugging) are online.

Comment: Are you sure that seq is exactly the same as omitting the policy? I don't think the standard guarantees that. On the contrary, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t states that this policy results in indeterminate sequencing of the element access functions.

Answer (score 113):

**What is the difference between `seq` and `par`/`par_unseq`?**

```
std::for_each(std::execution::seq, std::begin(v), std::end(v), function_call);
```

`std::execution::seq` stands for sequential execution. It is the default if you do not specify the execution policy at all. It will force the implementation to execute all function calls in sequence. It is also guaranteed that everything is executed by the calling thread.

In contrast, `std::execution::par` and `std::execution::par_unseq` implies parallel execution. That means you promise that all invocations of the given function can be safely executed in parallel without violating any data dependencies. The implementation is allowed to use a parallel implementation, though it is not forced to do so.

**What is the difference between `par` and `par_unseq`?**

`par_unseq` requires stronger guarantees than `par`, but allows additional optimizations. Specifically, `par_unseq` requires the option to interleave the execution of multiple function calls in the same thread.

Let us illustrate the difference with an example. Suppose you want to parallelize this loop:

```
std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3 };
int sum = 0;
std::for_each(std::execution::seq, std::begin(v), std::end(v), [&](int i) {
  sum += i*i;
});
```

You cannot directly parallelize the code above, as it would introduce a data dependency for the `sum` variable. To avoid that, you can introduce a lock:

```
int sum = 0;
std::mutex m;
std::for_each(std::execution::par, std::begin(v), std::end(v), [&](int i) {
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{m};
  sum += i*i;
});
```

Now all function calls can be safely executed in parallel, and the code will not break when you switch to `par`. But what would happen if you use `par_unseq` instead, where one thread could potentially execute multiple function calls not in sequence but concurrently?

It can result in a deadlock, for instance, if the code is reordered like this:

```
 m.lock();    // iteration 1 (constructor of std::lock_guard)
 m.lock();    // iteration 2
 sum += ...;  // iteration 1
 sum += ...;  // iteration 2
 m.unlock();  // iteration 1 (destructor of std::lock_guard)
 m.unlock();  // iteration 2
```

In the standard, the term is *vectorization-unsafe*. To quote from [P0024R2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0024r2.html#algorithms.parallel.exec):

> A standard library function is vectorization-unsafe if it is specified to synchronize with another function invocation, or another function invocation is specified to synchronize with it, and if it is not a memory allocation or deallocation function. Vectorization-unsafe standard library functions may not be invoked by user code called from `parallel_vector_execution_policy` algorithms.

One way to make the code above vectorization-safe, is to replace the mutex by an atomic:

```
std::atomic<int> sum{0};
std::for_each(std::execution::par_unseq, std::begin(v), std::end(v), [&](int i) {
  sum.fetch_add(i*i, std::memory_order_relaxed);
});
```

**What are the advantages of using `par_unseq` over `par`?**

The additional optimizations that an implementation can use in `par_unseq` mode include vectorized execution and migrations of work across threads (the latter is relevant if task parallelism is used with a parent-stealing scheduler).

If vectorization is allowed, implementations can internally use SIMD parallelism (Single-Instruction, Multiple-Data). For example, OpenMP supports it via [`#pragma omp simd` annotations](https://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/#SimdConstructOpenmp%204%200), which can help compilers to generate better code.

**When should I prefer `std::execution::seq`?**

1. correctness (avoiding data races)
2. avoiding parallel overhead (startup costs and synchronization)
3. simplicity (debugging)

It is not uncommon that data dependencies will enforce sequential execution. In other words, use sequential execution if parallel execution would add data races.

Rewriting and tuning the code for parallel execution is not always trivial. Unless it is a critical part of your application, you can start with a sequential version and optimize later. You also might want to avoid parallel execution if you are executing the code in a shared environment where you need to be conservative in resource usage.

Parallelism also does not come for free. If the expected total execution time of the loop is very low, sequential execution will most likely be the best even from a pure performance perspective. The bigger the data and the more costly each computation step is, the less important the synchronization overhead will be.

For instance, using parallelism in the example above would not make sense, as the vector only contains three elements and the operations are very cheap. Also note that the original version - before the introduction of mutexes or atomics - contained no synchronization overhead. A common mistake in measuring speedup of a parallel algorithm is to use a parallel version running on one CPU as the baseline. Instead, you should always compare against an optimized sequential implementation without the synchronization overhead.

**When should I prefer `std::execution::par_unseq`?**

First, make sure that it does not sacrifice correctness:

- If there are data races when executing steps in parallel by different threads, `par_unseq` is not an option.
- If the code is *vectorization-unsafe*, for instance, because it acquires a lock, `par_unseq` is not an option (but `par` might be).

Otherwise, use `par_unseq` if it is a performance critical part and `par_unseq` improves the performance over `seq`.

**When should I prefer `std::execution::par`?**

If the steps can be executed safely in parallel, but you cannot use `par_unseq` because it is *vectorization-unsafe*, it is a candidate for `par`.

Like `par_unseq`, verify that it is a performance critical part and `par` is a performance improvement over `seq`.

**Sources:**

- [cppreference.com (execution policy)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t)
- [P0024R2: The Parallelism TS Should be Standardized](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0024r2.html#algorithms.parallel.exec)

Comment: u could have used `recursive_mutex` because atomics is not always an option

Comment: What is the purpose of using the parallelized version with mutex comparing to a sequenced version? The mutex will make the change to the sum sequenced anyway, is not it?

Comment: @JenyaKh Yes, here in the example of summing up numbers, parallelizing it and having the whole computation protected by a mutex is not something that you would see in practice. Adding the mutex will restore correctness, but the code will be extremely slow. Sequentially summing it up will be faster. In more complex examples, the loop could have parts that can execute in parallel; then protecting only those could result in a speedup compared to a sequential loop. But it is true that the combination of a parallel loop with only a critical section as a body is worse then a sequential loop.