# What's the point of std::execution::par_unseq?

Tags: c++, multithreading, algorithm, concurrency, c++17

C++17 introduces execution policies, `std::execution::seq`, `std::execution::par` and `std::execution::par_unseq`, which can specify the standard algorithms to execute in a particular execution strategy.

`std::execution::seq` makes an algorithm to execute in a single thread and in deterministic order, i.e. **not parallel and not concurrent.**

`std::execution::par` makes an algorithm to execute in multiple threads, and the threads have their own sequential task(s) each. i.e. **parallel but not concurrent.**

`std::execution::par_unseq` makes an algorithm to execute in multiple threads, and the threads can have concurrent multiple tasks. i.e. **parallel and concurrent.**

But what's the point to have concurrent multiple tasks, as it just has more danger of data race than its sequential equivalent?

**Disclaimer to duplicate tag:** I already know how they are different. And thus the referred question is a different question. I don't think the answer to that question answers also me.

Comment: From my understanding, par_unseq potentially allows more optimizations. Vectorization (as the name implies) but also when internally task stealing workarounds are used and work is moved from one thread to another. I touched a bit of that in my answer to the question that is currently marked as a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47706880/783510 But I also think that your question is not a perfect duplication, as it is more about the optimization part, so I voted to reopen it.

Comment: @PhilippClaßen Thank you very much. So in summary, `std::par_unseq` is more optimizable.

Comment: @DannyuNDos Yes, that is my understanding. I don't have number to back up how relevant the effect is in real code, but the implementations have more options for optimization.