# How to replace the 2D vector corresponding to the values?

Tags: c++

I am trying to replace the elements in a 2D vector (`vector<vector<int>>`). I want to change the elements not only by one value, but by a list, which means, for example, change `1,3,4,5,8,9` to `1,2,3,4,5,6` one-to-one correspondence. I have made a very slow code with double loops. Is there any way to speed up the process, with new function or sort the element? Because my 2D vector is very big, 3*300000 actually. My example code is below:

```
int myints[] = { 1,3,4,5,8,9 };
int myints2[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6 };
std::vector<int> vals (myints, myints+6); 
std::vector<int> vals2 (myints2, myints2+6); 
vector<vector<int>> V0(3);
V0[0]={1,4,5};
V0[1]={3,1,8};
V0[2]={1,9,4};
for (size_t j = 0; j < V0.size(); j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < vals.size(); i++)
    replace(V0[j].begin(), V0[j].end(), vals[i], vals2[i]);
};
```

The ideal output `V0` should be

```
1 3 4
2 1 5
1 6 3
```

Comment: Your algorithm is slightly unclear, mostly because the example output you gave seems to have errors. For example, where would a 6 have come from? It wasn’t in `myints` or V0. Could you please double check the example output.

Comment: Another thing to look at is that you may be trying to write elements into V0 without actually initialising it with enough space.

Comment: @ChrisPearce Sorry for forgetting initializing capacity of the `V0`. I have change the example codes more clearly to understand. It is just a `paired replacement`. 1 to 1, 3 to 2,4 to 3, 5 to 4, 8 to 5 and 9 to 6. The 6 is from the initial 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [`unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) to replace each value directly, instead of searching through the whole vector for each replacement:

```
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unordered_map<int, int> replacements{{1, 1}, {3, 2}, {4, 3}, {5, 4}, {8, 5}, {9, 6}};
    vector<vector<int>> v0(3);
    v0[0] = {1, 4, 5};
    v0[1] = {3, 1, 8};
    v0[2] = {1, 9, 4};
    for_each(v0.begin(), v0.end(), [&](vector<int>& v)
    {
        transform(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(), [&](int val)
        {
            auto it = replacements.find(val);
            return it != replacements.end() ? replacements[val] : val;
        });
    });
    // Print
    for (auto& v : v0)
    {
        cout << "[ ";
        for (auto val : v)
        {
            cout << val << ", ";
        }
    cout << "]" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
[ 1, 3, 4, ]
[ 2, 1, 5, ]
[ 1, 6, 3, ]
```

In C++17, you may also choose a parallel [execution policy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t) in [`for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) and/or [`transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform), since all the changes can be done in parallel.

Comment: Thank you. Besides, Is your above code in parallel with `transform` or in serial?

Comment: @ZhangWei When no execution policy is specified, the algorithm will run sequentially (see [Difference between execution policies and when to use them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39954678)).